# Java Challenge for beginners: Generate random numbers in a while loop

Tags: java

This challenge taken from chapter 4 ["Java Programming For Absolute Beginners" by Joseph P. Russell.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0761535225)

> Write a `while` loop that generates random numbers between 1 and 100 and
>   stops looping after it generates the same number twice.

My largest concern is that I can't figure out how to keep initializing an array (if you use arrays here at all) because I don't know the size of an array (if that makes any sense).

Can I get some guidance?

Comment: You can use an array of boolean of size 100.

Comment: This is not a challenge; this is homework.

Comment: Easy homework at that. The kind of stuff...well I'll stay quiet.

Comment: if I don't know something - I ask, so keep smart comments for yourself

Comment: To make this more interesting, instead of an array of 100 `bool`s, you can use two `long`s. Hint: use bit-wise acrobatics.

Answer (score 9):

If the random numbers are only generated between 1 and 100, then use an array of size 100. However, in general, the problem is solved by a more generic associative container, e.g. HashMap, where contiguous keys are not required.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a hashed set. java.util.HashSet<T> is probably better suited than HashMap for this task, though.

Answer (score 2):

If "you don't know the size of an array" then you need an "array" witch grows dynamically... this is an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Obviously there are much more efficient methods but I think this will be just fine for now.

Comment: unfortunately, Mr. Russell didn't introduce me to ArraList yet, so it's got to be another way.

Comment: @lemmetry I really don't understand this "I haven't learned it in class so its forbidden" attitude the comp sci students seem to have. University is all about self directed learning

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an implementation of a Java `Set`, which ensures that there are no duplicate elements (an easy way to detect a duplicate).  However, declaring a simple `int[] numbers = int[100]();` array will also do the trick :-).

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean yourLoop = true;
    //you'll need to import java.util.ArrayList;
    ArrayList yourNumber = new ArrayList();

    //condition so your loop will run
        while (yourLoop){

            //get your first number to put in the array list, you need to cast as an int 
            int randNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
            //condition to check if the number is in the array list
            if (yourNumber.contains(randNumber)) {
                //print out the number that matched
                System.out.println(randNumber);
                //break the while loop
                yourLoop = false;
            }
            else {
                //add the number to your array list
                yourNumber.add(randNumber);
                //print out the array list
                System.out.println(yourNumber);
                //get another iteration
                yourLoop = true;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like the logic would be to initialize a 100-length array, as well as a zero-indexed counter variable. while true, create a random round number between 1 and 100. Check the index of the generated number in the array. If not found, then add the number and increment your counter.

The following is pseudo code.

```
int nums[] = new int[100];
counter = 0;
while(true) {
    test = random(1, 100);
    if(nums.indexOf(test) != -1) {
        return;
    }

    nums[counter] = test;
    counter++;
}
```